# Problem with unix pipe command

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a list of directory names in a text file. I want to use these as part of a file_name a git-svn clone command.

This prints out the contents of the file line by line.

```
cat repos_to_migrate.txt | tee $1
```

This however does not work:

```
cat repos_to_migrate.txt | git svn clone file:///home/svn/$1
... Unable to open repository 'file:///home/svn' ...
```

Any ideas here? I'f it matters I'm running centos5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
    while read repo; do
        git svn clone file:///home/svn/$repo
    done
) < repos_to_migrate.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working great so far. If a command failed the script would continue correct?

Comment: If you mean if one of the `git svn clone` operations would fail, then yes, it would continue with the next one.

Comment: If you want to abort instead of continue on failure, just add `set -e` on a line before the `while`.

Comment: Or use `git svn clone ... || exit`.